# MacOS File System

Tags: macos, file, system, finder

My Android SDK folder is apparently installed at: `/Users/<myComputerName>/Library/Android/SDK`

But when I use finder to go into my "Library" folder, I cannot find the "Android" folder.

I can go to the "Android" folder on the Mac Terminal using the `cd` command. So why cant I use finder to visually locate this folder?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Try this - Command + Shift + G >> /Users/Library/Android >> Enter/Return

Comment: Thanks! It does take me to the folder. How come I cannot see it though?

Comment: This is because the user library folder is hidden by default.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're visiting the Library folder which is in your home folder, not the one at the root of your hard drive. macOS has three Libraries; one in your home folder for user-specific items, one at the root for global items, and one in /System for things that are baked into the system which you generally shouldn't modify.

Note that on some versions of macOS, the home Library directory is hidden by default. You can turn that off by going to your Home directory, choosing "View Options" (⌘-J), and turning on "Show Library Folder". Alternatively, you can hold down either the Shift or Option (⌥) key (the exact key to do this varies depending on OS version) while choosing "Library" from the Finder's "Go" menu.

Comment: @Wes H I believe this is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Because user's library folder is by default hidden, try using

`Command + Shift + G >> (Type in the box that pops up) ~/Library/Android >> Enter/Return`

The above is also possible with

`Open Finder >> Click Go >> Click Go to folder...`